# Matrices, their subspaces and transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $D$ be the set of diagonal $2x2$ matrices.

Given this the matrix $D$ looks like: $span\{\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\0 & c \end{bmatrix}\}$

$1)$Show that $D$ is a subspace of $M_{2x2}$

To be a subspace the vector space must $(D\le M_{2x2})$:
$$\overrightarrow{0} \in D$$
$$\overrightarrow{u}+\overrightarrow{v} \in D$$
$$C\overrightarrow{u} \in D$$
For the zero vector: let $a=0,c=0 \therefore \overrightarrow{0} \in D$

For the vector addition: let $\overrightarrow{v_1}=\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & 0 \\0 & c_1 \end{bmatrix}$ , $\overrightarrow{v_2}=\begin{bmatrix}a_2 & 0 \\0 & c_2 \end{bmatrix}$ where $a_1,c_1,a_2,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ $\therefore \overrightarrow{u}+\overrightarrow{v} \in D$

For scalar multiplication: let $\overrightarrow{v_1}=\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & 0 \\0 & c_1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R} \therefore b\overrightarrow{v_1}= \begin{bmatrix}ba_1 & 0 \\0 & bc_1 \end{bmatrix} \in D$

$2)$What is the dimension of $D$?

Since $D= span\{\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\0 & b \end{bmatrix}\}$ the dimension is $2$ because $D$ is only the diagonal matrices of $M_{2x2}$, it can only be expressed by these $2$ matrices.

$3)$ Consider a coordinate mapping $T$:$D → \mathbb{R}^{
dim(D)}$. Explain what $T\begin{pmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0 &b \end{bmatrix} \end{pmatrix}$

I said that $T$ is the transformation that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{
dim(D)}$ which in this case is $\mathbb{R}^2$.

There are 2 more parts to this question but before I go any further I wanted to make sure I am on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given this the matrix $D$ looks like: $span\{\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\0 & b \end{bmatrix}\}$

What I think you mean to say is the **set** $D$ looks like
$$D = \operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right\}.$$
Note that the span will include not just sums of matrices, but linear combinations of matrices. The matrices in the span on the right hand side take the form:
$$a\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + b\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a & 0 \\0 & b \end{bmatrix}$$
for $a, b \in \Bbb{R}$, i.e. the diagonal $2 \times 2$ real matrices, i.e. the contents of $D$. The matrices used to span $D$, a fixed set, should not depend on variables such as $a$ and $b$.

> For the vector addition: let $\overrightarrow{v_1}=\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & 0 \\0 & c_1 \end{bmatrix}$ , $\overrightarrow{v_2}=\begin{bmatrix}a_2 & 0 \\0 & c_2 \end{bmatrix}$ where $a_1,c_1,a_2,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ $\therefore \overrightarrow{u}+\overrightarrow{v} \in D$

The other arguments, regarding scalar multiplication and (particularly) the zero vector, are clear. I think you just skipped a step where you point out that
$$\vec{v}_1 + \vec{v}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 + a_2 & 0 \\ 0 & b_1 + b_2 \end{bmatrix}$$
is a diagonal matrix (taking $a = a_1 + a_2$ and $b = b_1 + b_2$). I think you understand this, but the written argument looks like it just jumps to the conclusion.

> Since $D= span\{\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\0 & b \end{bmatrix}\}$ the dimension is $2$ because $D$ is only the diagonal matrices of $M_{2x2}$, it can only be expressed by these $2$ matrices.

You seem to be arguing the set is a $2$-element basis, and concluding that $D$ has dimension $2$. This is a good idea: counting the size of a basis is what you should be doing. That said, as above, there should be no $a$ or $b$ in the span, and the matrices $\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ should be used instead. And, indeed, these matrices span $D$. If you want to be sure that they form a basis (and hence $D$ indeed has dimension $2$), you should also argue (or at least mention) that they are linearly independent.

> I said that $T$ is the transformation that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{
> dim(D)}$ which in this case is $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I can't really tell what you're saying here. Transformations like $T$ are not isomorphic to vector spaces like $\mathbb{R}^2$. You'll need to look at your notes about coordinate maps again; once you've picked an ordered basis for $D$, this completely defines the coordinate map. You should be able to say which vector in $\Bbb{R}^2$ the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix}$ maps to.

Comment: For the transformation T, I'm guessing the vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that maps $\begin{bmatrix} a & 0\\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix}$ is the basis  $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. My reasoning being that it is linearly independent and spans all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and is equal to the dimension of $D$.  Also should I edit my question to follow your answers or leave it alone? and if I had more parts to add would that be okay?

Comment: Regarding the basis, you're not choosing a basis for $\Bbb{R}^2$, you are choosing a basis for $D$. You should be able to write any diagonal $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ as a unique linear combination of matrices in this basis, of which there must be $2$. The coefficients of this linear combination define the vector of $\Bbb{R}^2$ that $T$ maps $A$ to. When I said you should be able to say what vector $\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{bmatrix}$, it should be a single vector in $\Bbb{R}^2$, depending on $a$ and $b$, not a fixed matrix like the identity matrix.

Comment: As another, similar example, the matrices $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, and $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ form a basis for the space of symmetric $2 \times 2$ real matrices. I can write an arbitrary such matrix as:$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$So, this means the coordinate map $T$, to $\Bbb{R}^3$, maps$$T\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a\\c\\b\end{bmatrix},$$from reading off the coefficients.

Comment: Regarding editing, I would not change the errors in the post and make my answer redundant. If you want, you can edit in a second attempt, so long as you make clear what is an edit and what was there originally. You can also just keep engaging with me in comments if you're happy with my input on the topic; I'm happy to answer follow-up questions.